# UITextField.autocorrectType issue in iOS 7

Tags: ios7

This is occurring with existing apps running on iOS7 and also with apps compiled in XCode 5.0.

I have recently inherited two iOS apps that were built using the Three20 framework. I realize that this framework is no longer supported, and do eventually want to switch these apps to a different framework.  I am trying to simply get them to run under iOS7 before making an infrastructure changes.

The apps use a text field which inherits from a Three20 class, ultimately deriving from UITextField.
The inheritance chain is:
  MyAppPickerTextField
    TTPickerTextField 
      TTSearchTextField
        UITextField

The apps are crashing when the initWithFrame method of MyAppPickerTextField is called, with the following exception:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyAppPickerTextField setAutocorrectionType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd1c6c30'

It appears that somewhere in the inheritance MyAppPickerTextField is losing UITextInputTraits, which UITextField implements.

I've tried to implement UITextField at all levels of the inheritance chain with no results.
Could it be that the instance of MyAppPickerTextField is getting deleted before that gets called?

Thanks

Comment: Be aware that iOS 7 and Xcode 5 are still under NDA. As long as your question and answers don't discuss iOS 7-specific API's or Xcode 5-unique stuff, you're ok. Otherwise, ask in the Apple Developer forums.

Comment: Any updates on this bug? Three20 seems to have more issues like dynamic height to textboxes.